# Finding AniMove in QGIS 2.x?

Tags: qgis, sextante

I've just upgraded to Valmiera in QGIS, the only way to do spatial analyses appears to be with the experimental AniMove plugin (?) which is not appearing in my GUI.

Can anyone tell me where to find the plugin and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The Ani move Plugin still is in an experimental stage.

So you have to go unter `Plugins -> Manage & Install Plugins -> Settings`, and enable to show experimental plugins as well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Processing > Options and Configuration**, and do click to activate the AniMove plugin. After that, the plugin appears in the tool box.

[image]